# Creating and Open Graph Action with more than one object

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create an Open Graph action similar to the one used by Farm Heroes Saga where it states "{User} gave a life to {Friend} in {Game}". But i couldn't link two objects (Life and Profile for this example) to the action Give.

Is there anything special i need to do to accomplish the same result as they did?